# How to reference an html document with a form to another html document to create a table out of that?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a little bit of help. I'm stuck at making the form information I have on my first html document show up on the tables in the second html document. 
Any help would really feel good right now.

Comment: You're going to need a server to do that. Is there a particular server environment you're working with, or are you just writing html directly?

Comment: is not possible, references html to another html an build a table of that...

mismatched a programing language server side, or uses a javascript to generate data in raw mode, hmtl inst capable to read anything...

Comment: hey doing this for a school assignment so yeah forgot to say if we need to use javascript that is also an option, I'm just really stuck here and not really used to html and javascript...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your question means, but if you are asking about including an html inside another html, check this link: [include html in another html](https://www.beyondjava.net/html-includes)

Edit:
If you have no option to use server-side programming, you could use the query string.

In the form, add a method="GET" attribute:

```
<form action="display.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    <input type="text" name="phone" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When they submit this form, the user will be directed to an address which includes the name, phone value as a parameter. like:
http://www.example.com/display.html?name=XYZ&phone=98745654

You should then be able to parse the query string - which will contain the parameters value - from JavaScript, using the window.location.search value:

```
// from display.html
<p id= 'hi' ></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = window.location.search;
</script>
```

this should help you to start what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I already know how to do this, it really is a bit difficult to explain. Basically I have one page with a form that the user needs to fill, when he clicks on submit It needs to go on the second page that has a table of all attributes that are mentioned in the form, except it needs to be filled with the answers the user provided. Hope you can understand

Comment: I edited my Answer, I think that should help you. @no_va